# Automatically scale big and small graphics for beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, graphics

For the next few semesters I'll be making a lot of beamer presentations with a lot slides that are just a frame title and a figure. I am trying to make a command to make a lot faster to code and easier to read. Here is my first attempt:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand {\framedgraphic}[2] {
\begin{frame}{#1}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics{#2}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
}
```

In this past I've have scaled manually with something like

```
\includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight]{table3a.png}
```

Through trial and error I have to find the right scaling to make the figure fill the slide. Is there a way I can automatically do this scaling without adding more arguments to my command? Including covering both wide and tall figures? Thanks!

BTW, here I'm using `graphicx` but I'm not really wed to it. I am just getting started in TeX and would love to learn any new ways of thinking of this problem.

Comment: I know that problem. The available height depends on the used beamer style. The fame title (and sub-title if present) counts as part of `\textheight`. AFAIK there is no length which stores the rest of the height.

Comment: Note that the `figure` environment is for floating figures, which doesn't make sense in a presentation. They are not required for `\includegraphics` to work. Simply remove them here.

Comment: Beamer defines `\headheight` and `\footheight`, but it seems that `\textheight-\headheight-\footheight` is bigger then the actual height you have available.

Comment: `figure` is not a floating environment inside beamer

Comment: @Martin, @Herbert -- Thanks! Any idea on scale to fit?

Comment: Not more than `\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth,height=\myheight,keepaspectratio]{image}` where `\myheight` = `\textheight` - *some guessed value*.

Comment: @Martin -- Thanks! I didn't about `keepaspectratio` to take up the slack in the non-binding dimension. I'll post the solution as an edit above for you to cut in paste as a solution I can accept?

Comment: @richardh: I think Martin won't object if you answer your question yourself, saying that you got the answer with Martin's help in the comments. Then you can accept your own answer (and remove the answer from the question, as it's best _not_ to have answers in questions).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Martin's comment had the fix. Here's what I'm using:

```
\newcommand {\framedgraphic}[2] {
    \begin{frame}{#1}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#2}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've come across another solution to this problem that is slightly different because it takes up the entire page including margins. I have an analogous one for "fullheightgraphic" that uses \paperheight instead of paperwidth

```
\newcommand{\fullwidthgraphic}[2] {
   {
   \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperwidth]{#1}}
   \begin{frame}{#2}
   \end{frame}
   }
}
```

Comment: You may use `width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio` instead of two commands (`\fullwidthgraphic` and `\fullheightgraphic`).

Comment: You may use the `plain` frame option to remove title, headline and footline.