# Set image to full all available space in Beamer (without overlapping other elements)

Tags: beamer, graphics

I want to have an image take up as much as possible of the content area in a `beamer` presentation, without overlapping the title, the sidebars, or the footers. How can I achieve this?

The code below gives an example of what goes wrong using `\includegraphics` and setting the width and height from `\textwidth` and `\textheight` -- if you try it, you'll see that the footer at the bottom is covered.

One can, of course, do something like `height=0.9\textheight` but that is annoying and not particularly robust if one changes themes... I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Marburg}
}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Header}{Sub title}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{tmp.jpg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somewhat related question (the problem is the same, however no really satisfactory solution was provided): [Automatically scale big and small graphics for beamer presentations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11954/3323)

Comment: The post [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/stable-vertical-alignment-of-columns-in-beamer](stable-vertical-alignment-of-columns-in-beamer) also provides references to `\beamer@frametextheight` but I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to work

Comment: Great! `\beamer@frametextheight` seems like a good way to go. I had two problems with it: 1. It seems to be defined too late, when `beamer` actually typesets the slide. So in order to use it, you'll have to define your own version of the macro emulating its behaviour. 2. It only into account the height of the title, not the height of head- or footlines.

Answer (score 29):

The following code demonstrates how to include an image full-size. To customize it, simply change `image.jpg` to the file name of the picture you want to display. If you're using a `beamer` theme without a sidebar (such as the default one, `Ilmenau`, `AnnArbor`, ...), alter `\sidebarthemetrue` to `\sidebarthemefalse`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Marburg}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\newif\ifsidebartheme
\sidebarthemetrue

\newdimen\contentheight
\newdimen\contentwidth
\newdimen\contentleft
\newdimen\contentbottom
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\calculatespace}{%
\contentheight=\paperheight%
\ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\box\voidb@x%
  \else%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{%
      \vbox{}%
      {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}}%
    }%
    \ifsidebartheme%
      \advance\contentheight by-1em%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\advance\contentheight by-\ht\@tempboxa%
\advance\contentheight by-\dp\@tempboxa%
\advance\contentheight by-\beamer@frametopskip%
\ifbeamer@plainframe%
\contentbottom=0pt%
\else%
\advance\contentheight by-\headheight%
\advance\contentheight by\headdp%
\advance\contentheight by-\footheight%
\advance\contentheight by4pt%
\contentbottom=\footheight%
\advance\contentbottom by-4pt%
\fi%
\contentwidth=\paperwidth%
\ifbeamer@plainframe%
\contentleft=0pt%
\else%
\advance\contentwidth by-\beamer@rightsidebar%
\advance\contentwidth by-\beamer@leftsidebar\relax%
\contentleft=\beamer@leftsidebar%
\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\calculatespace%
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{background canvas}{}{\color{bg}\pgfusepath{fill}}
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\contentleft+0.5\contentwidth}{\contentbottom+0.5\contentheight}]{\includegraphics[width=\contentwidth,height=\contentheight]{image.jpg}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
}
\begin{frame}{Header}{Sub title}
Frame content
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Output result: A full sized-image]

<sub>(The image used is by Steve Peter and can be downloaded at http://www.tug.org/publicity/wallpaper/.)</sub>

---

### Explanation of the code:

#### 1. Calculating the space available to content

These dimensions will hold the height and width available and the absolute position of the content in relation to the lower left corner of the page (which is necessary when there is a left sidebar or a footline):

```
\newdimen\contentheight
\newdimen\contentwidth
\newdimen\contentleft
\newdimen\contentbottom
```

Themes with sidebars, such as `Marburg`, require some extra treatment, as there's a `\vskip-1em` in the definition of the `frametitle` template which distorts the calculations:

```
\newif\ifsidebartheme
\sidebarthemetrue
```

The macro `\calculatespace` is the core piece which computes all the lengths defined above:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\calculatespace}{%
```

We begin with `\paperheight` and subtract the height of the frame title and subtitle (code adapted from `beamerbaseframe.sty`, ll. 114-129):

```
\contentheight=\paperheight%
\ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\box\voidb@x%
  \else%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{%
      \vbox{}%
      {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}}%
    }%
    \ifsidebartheme%
      \advance\contentheight by-1em%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\advance\contentheight by-\ht\@tempboxa%
\advance\contentheight by-\dp\@tempboxa%
\advance\contentheight by-\beamer@frametopskip%
```

If it is a [plain frame](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=62), this is everything that has to be taken into account. Otherwise, also subtract the height of head- and footline (cf. `beamerbaseframecomponents.sty`, ll. 161-182):

```
\ifbeamer@plainframe%
\contentbottom=0pt%
\else%
\advance\contentheight by-\headheight%
\advance\contentheight by\headdp%
\advance\contentheight by-\footheight%
\advance\contentheight by4pt%
\contentbottom=\footheight%
\advance\contentbottom by-4pt%
\fi%
```

Like this, we have calculated `\contentheight` and `\contentbottom`. To obtain the content width, one has to subtract the width of the sidebars from `\paperwidth` if it's not a plain frame (`beamerbaseframesize.sty`, ll. 80-85):

```
\contentwidth=\paperwidth%
\ifbeamer@plainframe%
\contentleft=0pt%
\else%
\advance\contentwidth by-\beamer@rightsidebar%
\advance\contentwidth by-\beamer@leftsidebar\relax%
\contentleft=\beamer@leftsidebar%
\fi%
```

#### 2. Displaying the image

We now have a macro `\calculatespace` that computes all the necessary dimensions. It has to be called separately for each frame as the dimensions might change depending on whether you use titles and subtitles. The inclusion of the image is done in the `background canvas` template. It is scaled to the full width and height available and placed in the middle of the content space:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\calculatespace%
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{background canvas}{}{\color{bg}\pgfusepath{fill}}
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\contentleft+0.5\contentwidth}{\contentbottom+0.5\contentheight}]{\includegraphics[width=\contentwidth,height=\contentheight]{image.jpg}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
}
```

If you don't want the image to be distorted, simply add `keepaspectratio` as an optional argument to `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Brilliant. I have kept modified versions of the beamer base definition files for years, in order to have a frametextheight. Your code is now the core of a rewrite of a set of image-frame macros.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble getting your example frame to respect a \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}  command. If I include a keepaspectratio option in the includegraphics call, then there is some empty space in the content area. I to be able to control the color of that space, but cannot do it the way I am used to. Can you see the reason?

Comment: @CPBL I've modified the code so that `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}` should work as usual.