# "Grid" of background images in Beamer frame

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I am trying to get a 2x2 grid of background images in a Beamer frame.  I'd like the images to touch on all side (i.e., no whitespace around images).  I am able to get a tabular environment inside `\usebackgroundtemplate{}`, but I have to play with negative `\hspace{}` to eliminate the left "margin" (feels like a hack).  The problem is that the top row of images is behind the Beamer titles.  When I use a single background image, I am able to use something like `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,trim=0cm 0cm
  0cm -5cm,clip]{image.jpg}}` to push the image down below the Beamer titles.  That also feels like a hack, but it works.  However, I can't figure out how to do something similar with the tabular environment.  A MWE follows which also contains an attempt at using `minipage` environments, but all images end up in the same row despite trying many iterations of `\linebreak`, `\pagebreak`, etc.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Code for placeholder images
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\Ginclude@graphics#1{%
      \begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
      \fbox{\rule{\@ifundefined{Gin@@ewidth}{150pt}{\Gin@@ewidth}}{0pt}%
        \rule{0pt}{\@ifundefined{Gin@@eheight}{100pt}{\Gin@@eheight}}}\endgroup}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\def\arraystretch{0}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0cm}
\hspace*{-0.4cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{} \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{} \\
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Using tabular...}
\end{frame}
\usebackgroundtemplate{}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\begin{minipage}{1.0\paperwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\paperwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{}
\end{minipage}
}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Using minipage...} % All images end up on one line...
\end{frame}
\usebackgroundtemplate{}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

<sub>Image posted by JLDiaz</sub>

Comment: Welcome! I posted the image for you.

Comment: Yet another hack: put a first row in your table, before the figures , with: `\\[6mm]`

Comment: The `\hspace` "hack" can be easily avoided; you are leaving spurious blank spaces in your code; suppress them by using `% `right after `\def\arraystretch{0}` and `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0cm}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\hspace` "hack" can be easily avoided; you are leaving spurious blank spaces in your code; suppress them by using `%` right after `\def\arraystretch{0}` and `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0cm}`.

To place your grid, you can use TikZ with a `\node` containing the `tabular` array of images; the width of each image will be `0.5\paperwidth`; the tricky part is to calculate the precise height; the obvious choice, `0.5\textheight` (and not `0.5\paperheight`), won't be a good choice since it doesn't take into account the height of the `frametitle` box, so the height will be `0.5\textheight-0.5\ftht`, where `\ftht` represents the height of the `frametitle` box.

TikZ will then be used to place the node at `( $ (current page.center) + (0,-\ftht) $ )`; using `\ftht` in all the calculations will allow you to make the necessary adjustments (for example, if there's a theme change affecting the height of the default frametitle box) by simply making one change in the code. For example, for the Madrid theme the approximate value (obtained through trial/error) was `4ex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength\ftht
\setlength\ftht{4ex}

% Code for placeholder images
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\Ginclude@graphics#1{%
      \begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
      \fbox{\rule{\@ifundefined{Gin@@ewidth}{150pt}{\Gin@@ewidth}}{0pt}%
        \rule{0pt}{\@ifundefined{Gin@@eheight}{100pt}{\Gin@@eheight}}}\endgroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ( $ (current page.center) + (0,-\ftht) $ )
{
\def\arraystretch{0}%
\setlength\tabcolsep{0cm}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5\ftht\relax]{} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5\ftht\relax]{} \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5\ftht\relax]{} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5\ftht\relax]{} \\
\end{tabular}%
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Using tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, if a frame has a two line title (or no title), the value for `\ftht` will have to be changed.

Comment: See [Set image to full all available space in Beamer (without overlapping other elements)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44298/3323) for a (partly) automated calculation of the necessary dimensions: It still requires some adjustments for each theme (e.g. in this particular example, one would additionally have to take the shading of the `smoothbars` theme into account), but it should handle things like header or title height changes automatically in most cases.

Comment: This certainly works!  I'm not sure I understand why setting the node position at `$ (current page.center) + (0,-\ftht) $` works, though.  This is setting the location of the tabular environment... but seems to be locating a point "top-center" of the usable frame space (tikz coordinates are [X,Y], correct?)  I would have expected the coordinate to be "top-left", but perhaps I am not aware of how the tabular environment is laid out.  Regardless, I was able to also make this solution work for a single image in the background, and was able to eliminate `trim,clip` options from `\includegraphics`

Comment: @diabonas I tried that solution.  I really like the idea of being able to automatically calculate the required offset, but my document fails to compile and halts at the call to the macro `\calculatespace`.  I'm able to call each of the variables defined by the macro with `\the\contentheight` (for example), but all four report as 0.0pt.  Do I need to do anything special to get the macro to compile?  (I'm using Aquamacs+AUCTeX+PDFLatex)

Comment: @jjwebster I am working on a solution using **diabonas**'s answer, but some manual adjustments are still necessary in some cases. I'll add it in some minutes.

Comment: @diabonas nice approach. I'll add some answer here using your idea, if you're OK with that.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sure, go ahead! :-)