# Beamer: Full width image, aligned to top with a frame title

Tags: beamer, spacing, graphics

I would like to include a full width image, aligned to the top of a frame with a frame title. The problem is, I cannot get rid of a line of white space between the orange frame title header and the lion image.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
% Frames are 128x96mm and top-aligned by default.

% Calculate with \sidebarwidth
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\sidebarwidth}

% Theme
\setlength{\sidebarwidth}{28mm}
\usetheme[height=16mm, right, width=\sidebarwidth]{Goettingen}
% Hence, a full frame image is 100x80mm
\usecolortheme{crane}

% Include full-width graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\includefullwidthgx}[2][]{%
\noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]{\includegraphics[width=128mm-\sidebarwidth, #1]{#2}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title text}
\includefullwidthgx{lion.jpg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a beautiful picture for TeX site! :-)

Comment: That was on purpose! It is a Wikimedia Commons image. Here is the link to the original: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lion_in_masai_mara.jpg

Comment: If I'm not wrong, when you fix only one option `width` (or `height`) for `includegraphics`, option `keepaspectratio` is `true` by default, so image keeps its original proportions. If you want to cover all this area select another image or also fix option `height`.

Comment: Related questions: [Automatically scale big and small graphics for beamer presentations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11954/1952) and [Set image to full all available space in Beamer (without overlapping other elements)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44218/1952)

Comment: @Ignasi: I am aware of that, but I do not want to lose the white space below the picture.

Comment: Inserting `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before the `\includefullwidthgx{lion.jpg}` comes close to a solution, but it eats too much space.

Comment: I guess it all boils down to how that mystery space is called. A negative vspace would solve my issue then. As Ignasi pointed out, some interesting comments can also be read here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11954/automatically-scale-big-and-small-graphics-for-beamer-presentations No real solutions, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I helped myself out by adding a `\vspace{-9.5pt}`. The value seems not to change with standard themes. Nor does it matter whether a subtitle is present in the header. Still, I find it a non-general, somewhat sub-optimal solution. Who does better?

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
% Frames are 128x96mm and top-aligned by default.

% Calculate with \sidebarwidth etc.
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\sidebarwidth}

% Theme
\setlength{\sidebarwidth}{28mm}
\usetheme[height=16mm, right, width=\sidebarwidth]{Goettingen}
% Hence, a full frame image is 100x80mm
\usecolortheme{crane}

% Include full-width graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\includefullwidthgx}[2][]{%
\vspace{-9.5pt}
\noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]{\includegraphics[width=128mm-\sidebarwidth, #1]{#2}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sub-optimal solution.}
\framesubtitle{Anyone does better?}
\includefullwidthgx{lion.jpg}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am still looking for the mystery length;`\vspace{\topskip}` also eats too much space.

Answer (score 7):

The vertical space you see is composed of two parts, both of which are in some way specified in the `beamerbaseframe.sty`:

1. If the frametitle is non-empty, beamer appends a `\vskip0.25em` to the `\beamer@frametitlebox` (line 122). This is hard-coded but can be avoided by not specifying a frametitle.
2. In line 142 or 144, beamer issues a `\vskip\beamer@frametopskip`(`autobreak`). This skip is set depending on the vertical frame alignment (`t`/`c`/`b`); for `t` (top) it is `0.2cm plus…`. It is set in the `\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]` (line 258) and can be changed by modifying or overwriting this `\define@key`.

These two components add up to the vertical space in your example. Beamer does not offer a straightforward way of getting rid of it, so probably it thinks it is a good thing.