# Beamer frame environment introduces 5.69pt vertical margin

Tags: beamer, margins, beamerposter

I'm working on a beamer poster template where I need precise control over all margins. I got rid of most, but the mandatory frame environment<sup>(1)</sup> introduces a `5.69pt`<sup>(2)</sup> which I cannot find<sup>(3)</sup>.

Observe this example:

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a4]{beamerposter}
\geometry{margin=0pt}%

\begin{document}%
\begin{frame}[t,plain]%
%\vskip-5.69pt%    <--- magical vertical space
\begin{pgfpicture}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{-2cm}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfpicture} with frame%
\end{frame}%
\end{document}%
```

If we build this and zoom in on the top left corner it looks like this:

[image: vertical frame margin]

Now, if we remove the `\begin{frame}[t,plain]` and `\end{frame}` we get this:

[image: no vertical margin]

Note that the thin black frame around the picture is the page border inserted by my pdf viewer.

*I have no idea where the distance between the page border and the pdfpicture comes from. **How do I get rid of it?***

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I can omit the frame, but then I run into trouble with `\item`s in itemize environments. TeX then suddenly claims `\item` to be an undefined control sequence.

<sup>(2)</sup> That's the overfull-ness of the `\hbox` reported by latex when I try to insert a minipage of the dimension `[\paperheight]{\paperwidth}`.

<sup>(3)</sup> I tried setting [virtually every page margin](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) to `0pt` to no avail. Also, the official beamer guide does not mention this margin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a sneaky one: the `t` option doesn't push everything right to the top, it sets `\beamer@frametopskip` to `0.2cm plus 0.5\paperheight`. (0.2cm are pretty exactly the 5.69pt you observe).

Adding

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt %<-- was: .2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{%
    \def\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip{%
      \vskip-\partopsep\vskip-\topsep\vskip-\parskip%
      \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}%
    \everypar{\global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}}
}
```

seems to fix that issue, at least for the tiny example I tested.

Comment: Regrettably, Till hard-coded a lot of fixed distances into `beamer`: they make my life tricky!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Joseph. This reminded me of my problem with another fixed distance in beamer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110229/beamer-full-width-image-aligned-to-top-with-a-frame-title